# Spring MVC - Cannot call getWriter(), getOutputStream() already called

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jasper-reports, thymeleaf

Pdf file can be viewed fine, exception thrown in console.

I have researched, most questions were resolved by declaring method as void or returning null; tried same but error still thrown.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/repRange/view/pdf", method = RequestMethod.GET)/
public void viewRepRangeAsPdf(
        SaleReportRepOption options
        ) throws Exception{
    prepRepRange(options);
    saleReport.generateReport();
}
```

prepRepRange simply sets certain variables

```
private void prepRepRange(SaleReportRepOption options){
    saleReport.setJasperFilename("rpt_SaleRepRange.jasper");
    saleReport.setOutputFilename("saleRepRange.pdf");
    List<SaleReportRepInfo> saleReportRepInfo = saleReportRepInfoService.findAllByOption(options);
    saleReport.setContent(saleReportRepInfo);       
}
```

And finally report is generated here

```
public void generateReport() throws IllegalArgumentException, JRException, NamingException, SQLException, IOException {
    JasperReport jasperReport = getJasperReport(jasperFilename);
    JRDataSource jrDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(this.content);
    byte[] bytes = null;
    bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(jasperReport, parameters, jrDataSource);

    resp.reset();
    resp.resetBuffer();
    resp.setContentType("application/pdf");
    resp.setContentLength(bytes.length);
    String headerValue = headerValue = "inline; filename=" + outputFilename;
    resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", headerValue);
    ServletOutputStream ouputStream = resp.getOutputStream();
    ouputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    ouputStream.flush();
    ouputStream.close();
}
```

All methods complete successfully without throwing error. Error is thrown well after completion of controller viewRepRangeAsPdf(), somewhere within core files.

I don't write or output anything, all methods are also return void.

Stack trace

> ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-23) UT005023: Exception
>   handling request to /aiwaweb/saleReport/repRange/view/pdf:
>   org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010006: Cannot call getWriter(),
>   getOutputStream() already called  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010006: Cannot call getWriter(),
>   getOutputStream() already called  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.getWriter(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:353)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:152)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:152)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.getWriter(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:149)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1257)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>     ... 66 more

I use Spring Mvc 4.3.3.RELEASE, Thymeleaf 3.0.1.RELEASE, Jasper 6.4.3

Comment: @DaveJarvis Can you please elaborate? I thought I was already using servlet in Spring Mvc. Tnx

Comment: My mistake. Somewhere along the call chain, the output stream is used. Try overriding [doGet](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doGet-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-) directly, if possible, to ensure that no other code is touching the output stream.

Comment: @DaveJarvis thanks, looks like a lot of work for it. Will try & let u know